# logcat overflow

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

Is there any way to interrupt the logcat function in eclipse?

Ie, I added some log.d debugging stuff for testing. But once i got the app working as expected, 
But i forgot to take the specific line in the log away.
Then i preceded to "play with the app" - 
The line of code is in a place that would cause normal operation to write millions of log lines from the phone over the adb bridge.

I am writing this while im waiting for Eclipse to catch up... I suppose it will come unfroze in about 15 mins.

my previous work around was to xkill eclipse, but thats a nasty approach...

wait.. it stopped now. 
Next time I will try the adb kill-server command.

That would probably fix it. 
Ill check this thread if it happens again. Maybe someone else experiences this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well don't worry, you're not the first one to write a log function at the wrong place.

You got the solution, in such case call `adb kill-server` to stop the communication with the emulator or the device.

Comment: Sorry to say, but it seems like kill-server does not, in-fact, work. I think that the issue is not the adb logcat, but eclipse itself having a small heart-attack when it is bombarded with log lines.
even if you kill-server adb, its too late because (i think) the log lines are already "in the queue" for eclipse to display on the screen.